# Lining up two div's side by side (jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line up two div's inside of a larger one. One is for the left side, one is for the right. The left side I want at 100% height, as I do not want anything to be wrapped around it. Basically, I am trying to make two columns inside of a div, but I am having trouble getting them to align properly.

```
.outerbox {
width: 350px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.leftbox {
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid #666;
float: left;
height: 100%;
 }
.rightbox {
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid #FF0000;

}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LCtU/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into consideration the border width because your total width of `leftbox` & `rightbox` right now is `100% + 4px` (1px for each border, so 2px per box for the 2 side borders)

Try using `calc()`

```
.leftbox {
    width: calc(20% - 2px);
    border: 1px solid #666;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.rightbox {
    width: calc(80% - 2px);
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    float: left;
}
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2LCtU/1/

Answer (score 1):

Float the right `div` also, and adjust its size so that it fits within the outer div.

```
.rightbox {
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    float: left;
}
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/X656K/3/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to float the divs, you can usually get more predictable results if you set divs display to inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `display:table` in main container and `display:table-cell` in children elements like this:

**css**

```
.outerbox {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: table;
}
.leftbox {
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;

}
.rightbox {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LCtU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add some left margin to the rightbox.

```
.rightbox {
    margin-left: 21%;
    width: 79%;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;

}
```

Notice that `margin-left` + `width` = `100%`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LCtU/6/)